# Font data could not retrieved PdfSharp/MigradDoc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, report, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have an ASP .NET MVC web application and I'm using PdfSharp/MigraDoc to generate the reports. When I publish the application to azure and print the report the following exception is raised:

```
Internal error. Font data could not retrieved.
```

I have this method that define the report style and I choose the "Arial" font.

```
private void DefineStyle(Document document)
{
   Style style = document.Styles.AddStyle("Table", "Normal");
   style.Font.Name = "Arial";
   style.Font.Size = 9;
}
```

And in the final step I render the PDF calling this method:

```
public void RenderAsPdf(Document document, HttpResponseBase response, string title)
{
        PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
        renderer.Document = document;
        renderer.RenderDocument();

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        renderer.Save(stream, false);

        response.Clear();
        response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + title + ".pdf");
        response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
        response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        response.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        response.End();
    }
```

At this point below, that the exception is raised.

```
    renderer.RenderDocument();
```

I have already given full trust to my application and didn't work. I added this config in the web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I really don't know what to do... How can I solve this?
Thanks!

**Sorry for my english :(

Comment: Did you changed something in your codes after installing the 1.50 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the Arial font is installed on the server - or use a private font (include the font with your project).

The API has changed with version 1.50. A sample for version 1.50 can be found here:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=8961#p8961

A sample for the API used by version 1.3x can be found with the complete source package. See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PrivateFonts-sample.ashx